# Devise_invitable in rails 4?

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-2.0, devise-invitable

I am trying to use devise_invitable(0.1.3) in my application and my application already uses devise(3.1.0). I specified the devise_invitable in  my gem file and run bundle install it installed successfully but when i run any command it gives the following error:

Error:
 uninitialized constant DeviseMailer (NameError)

Can anyone tell what i am doing wrong?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Per the devise_invitable README, you need to be using the version straight from github if you are on Rails 4:

```
gem 'devise_invitable', :github => 'scambra/devise_invitable'
```